# Function Call Syntax?

Tags: c++, templates, functor

Reading "C++ Templates: The Complete Guide" Section 22.5.3

I'm confused over the syntax the author uses for function pointers. I believe this syntax is called the "Function Call Syntax"? I feel like I am missing something here..? I commented the section of the code in question.

```
template<typename F>
void my_sort(.., F cmp = F())
{
  ..
  if (cmp(x,y)) {..}
  ..
}

//*** WHAT IS THIS SYNTAX? ***
bool my_criterion()(T const& x, T const& y);

// call function with function pointer passed as value argument
my_sort(..., my_criterion);
```

I replaced all the ..'s with appropriate values and replaced the T to an int in my_criterion() and it still won't compile.

He first mentions this syntax is the section before it:

"As written, the advantage of this functor specification technique is that it is also possible to pass an ordinary function pointer as argument. For example:

```
bool my_criterion () (T const& x, T const& y);
```

The code I'm trying to compile based on excerpt from the book:

```
template<typename F>
void mySort(F cmp)
{
    std::cout << "mySort(F cmp)" << std::endl;
}

bool myCriterion()(int x, int y);
```

*error C2091: function returns function (referring to myCriterion)

Comment: What is the error message?  Also, please post some *actual* code.

Comment: error: C2091: function returns function. I copied the code from the book verbatim.

Comment: I mean the code you are actually trying to compile.

Comment: On a wild guess without more relevant information the author was probably giving a figurative example of how template arguments can be defaulted. By having `F cmp = F()` you can either use `my_criterion` or any other function for comparison in your `my_sort` template function. This book might be dated as with C++11 you would simply use `std::function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that it's a typo in the book. Quoting from the book:

> As written, the advantage of this functor specification technique is that it is also possible to pass an ordinary function 
>   pointer as argument. For example:

```
bool my_criterion () (T const& x, T const& y); 
// call function with function object 
my_sort (… , my_criterion);
```

The authors are clearly trying to declare and "ordinary function". The pair of parentheses right after the function name shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1):

My C++ is a bit rusty, but googling turned this up: [The Function Pointer Tutorials](http://www.newty.de/fpt/functor.html)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you are missing is a class called Functor:

here is a small example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


struct foobar {
  void operator()(int x, int y) {
    std::cout << x << y << std::endl;
  }
};

int main () {
  foobar()(10,20);
  return 0;
}
```